# How to convert DBT to Dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dbt, dataform

DBT hub has shared projects that I would like to re use in a Dataform project.

https://hub.getdbt.com/

Also there are community and company-managed dbt packages stored in Github.

Is it possible to migrate or convert them to Dataform? Is there a tool that would help to do it?

Comment: I don't know any tool for that. You can try to use GenAI tools to speedup the migration!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this article by [Wiktor Jurek](https://www.cobry.co.uk/moving-to-dataform-from-dbt-a-practical-guide-2023), that provides steps on to move from dbt to Dataform:

1. Set up the landing zone (by creating folders and configuring the dataform.json file)
2. Create sources files
3. Create the General Ledger file
4. Update the General Ledger code for Dataform
5. Execute code and explore the data